# Upgrade failed: SQL 2008 R2 SSRS (SharePoint Integrated) to SQL 2012

Tags: 2010, reporting-services

I upgraded a SharePoint-integrated SQL 2008 R2 SSRS server to SQL 2012 SSRS over the weekend.  The installer said that the installation succeeded, but it appears that the SSRS database upgrade* may have only partially succeeded.  When I attempted to access SSRS's settings after the upgrade, I received messages stating that "the report server database is an invalid version" and "The version of the report server database is either in a format that is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is '147'. The expected version is '162'."

From research I did over the weekend, my understanding is that the database upgrade happens automatically when SSRS comes online.  Is there a way to force it to retry the database upgrade without restoring?  If not, if I just restore the SQL2008R2 databases to the server, will it redo the upgrade automatically?

(*NOTE: The database upgrade I'm referring to is the SSRS Report Server database, not the database engine. The SSRS database is located on a separate server; SQL's database engine is not installed on the SharePoint server.)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new SSRS service application and specify the existing SSRS database, it will upgrade at that point in time.  The database will not be upgraded just by installing SSRS.

Comment: Is there a way to get it to upgrade the database after it has already been installed? Or will I need to remove SSRS from SharePoint and completely reinstall it?

Comment: To upgrade after installing SSRS, create the new SSRS 2012 SA and point it at the existing database.  It will upgrade the database when the new SA is created.